# href blade Laravel e Vue.js

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, laravel-blade

Estou fazendo a listagem dos fonecedores cadastrados e em cada linha existe um botão de edição, no href, preciso usar o encrypt e passar o id, porem esse id vem pelo Vue.js e o blade com o uso do {{ }} não reconhece a variavel do Vue.js, então minha dúvida é como fazer para passar esse id, segue meu código.

```
<tbody>
    <tr v-if="fornecedores.length == 0">
        <td colspan="5" class="text-center">NENHUM FORNECEDOR CADASTRADO</td>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="fornecedor in fornecedores" :key="fornecedor.id">
        <td>@{{fornecedor.nome}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">@{{fornecedor.telefone1}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">@{{fornecedor.telefone2 ? fornecedor.telefone2 : '-'}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">@{{fornecedor.email ? fornecedor.email : '-'}}</td>
        <td class="text-nowrap text-center">
            <a href="{!! route('admin.fornecedores.gerenciar', encrypt(fornecedor.id)) !!}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Alterar"> <i class="fa fa-pencil text-inverse m-r-10"></i> </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Quero ajudar ms não conheço o laravel-blade. O que são os `@`? e `{!!`? Podes colocar na pergunta o código que chega ao browser?

Answer (score 0):

Esse problema ocorre porque o blade utiliza os mesmos delimiters que o Vue.js utiliza por padrão, o que faz com que o Blade tente interpretar variáveis do Vue e assim gere inconsistências em sua execução.

Para solucionar esse problema, o vue disponibiliza em sua [API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters) a propriedade "delimiters", no qual permite a alteração de quais delimitadores serão utilizados.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: data,
    delimiters: ["${","}"]
});
```

Este código modifica os delimitadores do Vue.js para ${alguma_coisa}, então em vez de {{alguma_coisa}} você passaria a utilizar ${alguma_coisa}.

Outra discussão relacionada: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628558/vue-js-change-tags